# Extracting One Time Password from email

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to extract One Time Password (OTP) from email, storing it in the Excel sheet?

**Scenario:**
Log in to an account with username and password but after login user needs to enter OTP which is mailed to the user's email id.

Comment: There are two options to perform this scenario, either go with the `Email parsing` or if the otp gets stored in `Database`, fetch it from there.

Comment: Yes .. you can write program to open your email parse and get the OTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait `Thread.sleep(15000);` when email is opened and then copy OTP string and continue testing with remaining instructions you have added on script.